# Can't PDO with multiple select LIKE

Tags: php, pdo

Having trouble with the following code. It's not giving an error nor does it output anything. The problem is with the `multipleReg` part. If I remove `bindValue multiplereg` and replace `:multiplereg` in the select statement with `$multipleReg` it works. I have a feeling it's cause it's not an array but I've tried executing it as an array which has not worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
require "includes/config.php";

$offset = $_GET["offset"];
$region = trim($_GET["region"]);
$regionExp = explode(",", $region);
$tag = $_GET["tag"];

$data = array();

foreach ($regionExp as $singleReg)
    $queryKeyword[] = "'%$singleReg%'";

$multipleReg = implode(' OR region LIKE ', $queryKeyword);

try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`tag`, :tag) AND 
(region LIKE :multipleReg) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offsetNr";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':tag', $tag);
$stmt->bindValue(':multipleReg', $multipleReg);
$stmt->bindValue(':offsetNr', (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
$stmt->closeCursor();
exit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot bind parts of the SQL syntax, it is only for values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array to prepare your SQL string and another to store placeholders :

```
$qstr = [];
foreach ($regionExp as $k => $singleReg) {
    $queryKeyword[':lk'.$k] = "%$singleReg%";
    $qstr[] = 'region LIKE :lk'.$k ;
}
```

Then your SQL query (don't forget to check if `$qstr` is not empty) :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`tag`, :tag) 
   AND (".implode(' OR ', $qstr).") 
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offsetNr";
```

And to bind :

```
// Instead of : $stmt->bindValue(':multipleReg', $multipleReg);
foreach ($queryKeyword as $k => $v) $stmt->bindValue($k, $v);
```

---

**EDIT** The full code :

```
$offset = $_GET["offset"];
$region = trim($_GET["region"]);
$regionExp = explode(",", $region);
$tag = $_GET["tag"];

// This part has changed :
$qstr = [];
foreach ($regionExp as $k => $singleReg) {
    $queryKeyword[':lk'.$k] = "%$singleReg%";
    $qstr[] = 'region LIKE :lk'.$k ;
}

try {

    // The SQL string changed
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`tag`, :tag)
            AND (".implode(' OR ', $qstr).")
            ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offsetNr";

    // Debug (see below)
    // echo $sql."\n" ;
    // print_r($queryKeyword);

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':tag', $tag);

    // The line below replaced
    foreach ($queryKeyword as $k => $v) $stmt->bindValue($k, $v);

    $stmt->bindValue(':offsetNr', (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    exit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The SQL and dump will look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`tag`, :tag)
   AND (region LIKE :lk0 OR region LIKE :lk1)
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offsetNr

Array
(
    [:lk0] => %test%
    [:lk1] => %test2%
)
```

Comment: Now it throws an error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. Your solution works if I only use one parameter for region, but for example if I use region=test1,test2 it throws the error.

Comment: Why would I need to do that? I tried it but that gives no results.

Comment: Yeah no problem dude. I'll update this post if I find a fix.

Comment: @CrimzonWeb I've tested (seems to have the right number of bound variable) and I've updated the answer with the full code. Could you check it please? Thank you.

Comment: That is reallllly weird. It works! I must've missed something, I even started over and tried again but no, didn't work. Thank you very much and my bad! :/ **EDIT** I think I figured out what It was, I left the $data = array(); out of the try catch block, and that seems to mess with it. May I ask why did you put it in the try catch block? Im just curious! :) Yet again, my bad.

Comment: @CrimzonWeb No worries :) My initial answer was not very clear! No, putting `$data` inside or outside the `try{}` don't change anything, IMO. I just put it there because it wasn't used elsewhere. Thank you for checking twice my answer!

Comment: Interesting! Maybe it was a small type or something I missed in there then! Thanks again!